# How to cast types with json_serializable in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serializable

Is there some way to cast double value from json to int field **using json_serializable** for code generation? Maybe some annotation? Couldn't find anything like this myself yet.

From json like this

```
{
  "number": 1.0,
  ...
}
```

To class like this

```
class MyClass {
  final int number;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some vsCode or Android Studio extension or map key to class

Like

```
import 'dart:convert';

SampleClass sampleClassFromJson(String str) => SampleClass.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String sampleClassToJson(SampleClass data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class SampleClass {
    SampleClass({
        this.number,
    });

    final int number;

    factory SampleClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => SampleClass(
        number: json["number"] == null ? null : json["number"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "number": number == null ? null : number,
    };
}
```

Most of time im using https://app.quicktype.io this site generating code with minimal modification